# Convert string into nested dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am newbie to python. I know this question has been asked many times before, but I looking to find solution to my query. I have a string(result of json.dumps) that needs to be converted into nested dictionary.

```
'["INPUT LABELS:\\n", "0 wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww\\n", "1 Input 2\\n", "2 Input 3\\n", "\\n","OUTPUT LABELS:\\n", "0 Output 1\\n", "1 Output 1\\n", "2 Output 3\\n", "\\n"]'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want the output to be?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I would like the output to be in the following format:{'INPUT LABELS': {0: 'wwwwwwwwwwwww', 1: 'Input 2', 2: 'Input 3'}, 'OUTPUT LABELS': {0: 'Output 1', 1: 'Output 2', 2: 'Output 3'}}

Comment: How would you insert `"1 Input 2\\n"` into a dictionary ?

Comment: I have tried using pyparsing and json, but haven't had any luck there.